# How to save text file without overwriting?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I want to save in a text file without overwriting the current data. I mean the next data that will be save will go to the new/next line whenever I save and that is my problem, I don't know how to do that.

Could someone help me about this matter?

Here's the code in save() method :

```
 public void save(String filename) throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    ObjectOutputStream outSt = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
    outSt.writeObject(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

> public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)   throws FileNotFoundException
>   Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the
>   specified File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will
>   be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. A new
>   FileDescriptor object is created to represent this file connection.

Comment: Yep, a native solution is the best solution.

Comment: @Atticus: Why do you suggest a native solution? And how is leonbloy's good suggestion (1+ to him) a native solution?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Because instead of making a work around, he is telling the OP that you can just include a boolean flag to append the new content rather than overwriting it... And since this is supported natively by the language, i called it a "native solution"

Comment: Hm, I consider *native* solutions, those that require native code, often written in C or C++ and often requiring JNI (Java *Native* Interface), or JNA (Java *Native* Access).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels are you trolling my use of the word native in this scenario? lol :)

Comment: @Atticus: I guess I may be.. Either that or pointing out that for many the term "native" has a very specific meaning in Java.